# How to increase max number of allocated inodes in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos

I have a Centos 6 server that is running kernel 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64.

I'm experiencing an issue in which the system is hitting the max number of **allocated** inodes. At this moment, inode-state returns this:

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/inode-state
279522  48040   0       0       0       0       0
```

I have 48040 inodes free, but several times per day this server will hit the limit ( it's a busy database server ).

Please, note that I'm not talking about used inodes, those defined in the file system. This is fine since when I run df -i, usage is only 14%.

How can I increase the allocated inodes limit? I saw that inode-max was removed in kernel 2.2 and couldn't find any other parameter related to this.

--- Edit ---

The used filesystem is ext4 and here is the output of df -i:

```
# df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            12804096 1783423 11020673   14% /
tmpfs                33062480      11 33062469    1% /dev/shm
```

Comment: What is the output of `sysctl fs.file-nr`? (# of allocated file handles, number allocated but not used and max).

Comment: @Brian Here is the output "fs.file-nr = 113024     0       7000000"

Comment: @Iain I'm using ext4. The error in Mysql is "2002: Resource temporarily unavailable". It's solved automatically since kernel seems to clear allocated inodes ( I can see it in munin at the moment that the error happens ).

Comment: Please remember to edit your question. Comments are only temporary, can be removed at any time, and some users don't see them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok, just added more info to the question.

Answer (score 1):

when you create ext2/ext3/ext4/ file system ,you can use -N to specify the numbers of inode exactly. once the file system  created , you can't change its value. but if you use LVM , you can still add inode numbers by expanding  filesystem  using resize2fs.